# Exiting United States with an expired passport

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork

Situation:

A person in the United States has an expired foreign passport and a Green Card.

Can he/she leave the United States with no issues to go to their home country?

Let's assume for the purpose of this question there is no transit point during flight.  Let's assume further that the entry on an expired passport is allowed under the laws of that country.

Answer (score 8):

[A passport is **not** required](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=PA&COUNTRY=us&SUBSECTION=PT&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) for green card holders to enter/exit the US, only a valid green card.

In fact, the US has no border control on exit.

So, if the other country accepts the expired passport, this trip is 100% fine.

Comment: And, if you're traveling by air, the airline needs to accept it too.

Comment: @ZachLipton The vast majority don't have their own rules, but refer you to "the embassy" of the destination country.

Comment: "no border control on exit": but airlines are supposed to enforce the documentation requirements for departing passengers.

Comment: @phoog Requirements which a valid green card alone fulfils

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @phoog Also they're not *always* enforcing it. My friend (EU citizen) had lost her passport in California and made it home on her ID card. And lastly, in Timatic the document requirements only appear when putting a WHTI country other than the French West Indies as the destination.

Comment: I suspected as much, which is why I said "supposed to." :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is no exit check on US borders, so the US can't stop you from exiting the country. You also don't need a passport for entry, just your Green Card.

However -

- Your airline would very likely not check you in and refuse you to board;
- Your destination country (even if it's your country of citizenship) would very likely deny you entry.

So, although you CAN exit and enter the US, there is nowhere much you could go.

Comment: There are countries that always let citizens in with expired passports and airlines know that. The UK is one that comes to my mind. And most or all countries let citizens in as long as they can proof they are citizens, even without a passport.